# If I delete my SO account, can I use my email on another account? 

Tags: discussion, user-accounts

Lets say I deleted my account, after a while I have a question that only can be answered on SO (just an example), Can I use the same email or not?

Comment: I'm not gonna delete my account...just wanna know

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, you can. For the same reasons that [you could create a second account](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/72277/why-are-people-allowed-to-have-multiple-user-accounts) using the same email address *without* deleting the first account.

I'm not really sure what the motivation would be behind either. Do note that deleting your account will not remove your contributions from the site, it will only prevent them from being attributed to you.

Comment: really? can i create a 2nd SO account without deleting my account? that's so strange!

Comment: @Eli: Yes. Perhaps even stranger yet, [user names are not required](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/25404/why-does-stack-overflow-allow-duplicate-display-names) [to be unique](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/27082/repeated-usernames).

Comment: WTF!! I can't believe this! usernames are not real names! they should not be real names! they should add a username field if they care about the real names...a user said `People have the same names in real life. Isn't StackOverflow real life?` but usernames are not names, so if SO is allowing us to use real names just to give us the freedom, they should add a username field to protect your privacy! and if i do care to know your name i go to ur account or something....that's shocking

Comment: and i can't believe that SO, is the one who did this `a website for professional programmers!` 14 years old kid writing a simple membership site wouldn't do that!

Comment: @Eli: I don't understand why you think user names need to be unique. The site has worked just fine for the past 3 or 4 years. Lots of people use their real name as their user name; there's nothing wrong with that. This is not a "membership site", it's a Q&A site. The focus is not on the members.

Comment: the url u gave me `to be unique` the asker called `beska` said: `That's a little weird/creepy. So I could name myself jjnguy, take your image, and go around trashing your good name? (The rep would be different, of course, but maybe people wouldn't realize that...)`

Comment: `And comments wouldn't even show you the rep...I could make all kinds of nasty comments that would be visually attributed to someone else. I could take the offensive-flag hit on my sockpuppet account at no cost, and possibly do damage to someone's rep. Long term, probably not a big problem, and I haven't really seen this (or have I, and I just don't know it?)...but it does give me the willies`

Comment: I agree with his point of view

Comment: `So I could name myself jjnguy, take your image, and go around trashing your good name?` if there was a problem with a user being intentionally malicious, then flag the account and moderators can deal with the problem user.  Almost everything you do is publicly visible in your profile, if you are confused then simply click on the username.  The fact that there really have been no major problems for several years indicate that you are worrying too much.

Comment: FWIW, I *have* seen this, @Eli - someone did it to me. He voluntarily left the site soon afterward.