# Misattributed posts and comments

Tags: support, display-names

I did not post [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14714798/attempting-to-fork-a-java-process-and-connect-rmi-as-client-but-forked-process-i), or the 2nd or 4th comments underneath it either. The user linked to the signature in the question isn't me either. Either you have a system fault or someone has been messing around.

Comment: I think someone has been messing around... And changed his name to yours. (or was just a coincidence)

Comment: @Mysticial There is indeed another user currently on a rampage against me and others, but I don't see how he could change a third user's name, or how anybody could change their name to one that already exists.

Comment: User names are not unique. It is just the display name.

Comment: @juergend You're kidding!

Comment: The other answer is a self-answer from the OP. So it's just the OP messing around.

Comment: Time to change my name to Jon Skeet!

Comment: So what's the *solution?* And why does SO allow other people to impersonate me?

Comment: @EJP: Always trust the user ID! Anyways, it's pretty hard to impersonate. Aside from the same name, his Gravatar, reputation, and badges are all different.

Comment: Well, there **are** about 50 billion people named John Smith. More than one of them joined SO. :)

Comment: @animuson If the displayed userID isn't unique in this system, this was not 'pretty hard' at all, and in any case it should be not 'pretty hard' but *impossible* to impersonate. UserIDs are unique in *all* the dozens if not hundreds of other systems I use, including the ones I build.  At present SO is putting about misleading information about me.

Comment: @EJP: I doubt you have the rights for your 3 letter name :)

Comment: +1 because I think this needs to be fixed.

Comment: @Juergen Of course I do. I had it first.

Comment: @EJP: User **IDs** *are* unique. User **names** are not. The user ID can be easily seen by hovering over the user link and looking at the number in the URL, or going to their profile and looking at the number in the address bar. It's not like it's completely hidden.

Comment: @Doorknob I don't think this can reasonably be fixed. What we going to do with all the legitimate dupes? You can't force anyone to change their names.

Comment: @animuson, Thanks, I am now aware of that, having been here several years already. I put it to you that this is a misfeature that needs correcting. At present there is material appearing over what appears to be my moniker that I didn't write. This is misrepresentation, and SO should neither perform nor permit it. There are some quite serious security and legal aspects to this that SO needs to think about, quickly.

Comment: @Mysticial EJP1 EJP2 EJP3

Comment: @Doorknob I think that would piss more than one person off. :P

Comment: @Mysticial ...yeah good point. :P

Comment: @EJP If the impersonator is intentionally impersonating you with bad intentions, I believe that warrants moderator action. Obviously I can't change my name and picture to Jon Skeet to fool people. (I'd get away with it for about 5 min. before a mod changes it back and suspends me.)

Comment: @Mysticial (a) I think it would benefit them actually. How many duplicate IDs are there, for a start? (b) Either the OP in the thread concerned is doing it, which is at least deliberately sowing confusion in that thread, which is actionable, or else the other party referred to (or someone else) is doing it, which is actionable as well. It was changed at least a day after the thread was created.

Comment: @EJP: Try a user search for the word "John"

Comment: @EJP Actually, http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/25404/why-does-stack-overflow-allow-duplicate-display-names

Comment: @Doorknob You have tons of work to do to get the rep to even come close to fooling anyone :P

Comment: @JoshMein Not just that actually. For someone like Jon Skeet, you also need to get 5 answers with more than 500 votes each including one with over 2k.

Comment: Not a bug, certainly, but I can't quite figure out *why* the other user would change their name to yours. It's probably nothing sinister, but I'm looking further into it just in case.

Comment: Are you sure it wasn't just entirely coincidence?  It's bound to happen sometime.  I can't find any reference that would indicate the other user's name is *not* `EJP`

Comment: @mellamokb It's a fairly recent name change. We keep a history.

Comment: @mellamokb I don't know where you can look, but I have stated it as a fact here. Changing a poster's name to that of a responder in the same thread is hardly coincidence, whoever did it.

Comment: @AnnaLear: Cool... Before I read this post, I didn't even know you could change the display name :)

Comment: [How to handle people impersonating other people by choosing the same display name?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/38466)

Comment: Woah, how did that banner get edited in? I don't see anything in the history.

Comment: @downvoters Please explain. I *did* post that question? The user *is* me? Someone *hasn't* been messing around? This isn't worthy of moderator attention?

Comment: @Mysticial: Seems to be a new feature within the last hour at most. Pre-closing "possible duplicate" banner.

Comment: @Mysticial It also gets auto-modified when the question is closed. No more automated edits by Community wooo (and no more users editing it out manually wooo)!!!

Comment: @animuson But the question isn't closed yet...

Comment: @Mysticial: I said *also*, as in it's meant to be taken in conjunction with Josh's comment. The feature popped up after the mass outage that has caused havoc on our dear Meta.

Comment: @animuson But feel that it can be abused if all it takes is one person to post a comment. Oh well, separate meta issue.

Comment: @Mysticial: Pretty sure it's dupe close votes, not the comment itself, that causes the banner. I believe I posted the link, then decided to VTC, and deleted the "possible duplicate..." auto-comment.

Comment: @JoshCaswell Even then it still can be abused. One dummy close vote and the banner is stuck there for 5 days. I can totally see someone doing this on a hot question to attract attention for another question. Unlike an edit, it can't be reverted.

Comment: @Mysticial: That's something to watch out for. I'm not sure yet whether I like the thing either.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I reverted the other user's name change.

While I don't know the exact reasons behind it and in principle there's no requirement for usernames to be unique, it's pretty clear that this was recent, intentional, and causing confusion. So... undone!

Comment: Many thanks. I believe this is the correct answer.

Comment: Anna, the [Content Policy](http://stackexchange.com/legal/content-policy) says: "Users that misleadingly appropriate the identity of another person are not permitted." It also says that this is grounds for suspension or removal of the offending user without notice.

Comment: @EJP That's at our discretion. This particular situation was resolved a week ago. Did something happen to stir it up again?

Comment: Yes, actually, my SO account has been suspended without notice.

Comment: @EJP Wasn't without notice, or at least not intentionally. You should've received two messages: http://stackoverflow.com/users/message/5773#5773 and http://stackoverflow.com/users/message/5779#5779 both as emails and as notifications on SO. You can chat with the moderators by replying to either one. (This was, by the way, completely unrelated to the name change incident.)

Comment: @EJP My apologies if the notifications didn't reach you. We've moved to a new datacenter and things have been a little wonky the last couple of days.

Comment: I received the first message by email. Just found the 2nd in the Junk folder for some reason. I've replied to the 2nd message on the site, but he posted it 9 hours ago, so he may not see it for another 15 hours. I'm not aware of anything that would motivate a suspension without notice. I'm posting here as I am wondering whether it is a result of another identity fraud.

Comment: @EJP This is completely unrelated.