# What are these questions with Yellow Highlighted box

Tags: support

On refresh of new questions some questions are highlighted with Yellow Background Box. i dont so any significance in those question and questions which are highlighted are random.

any one please explain what this means ? very curious..

Comment: They are questions with one of your favorite tags.

Comment: `Mystical` thanks. @Administrator do I need to close this question as I got the answer through comment ?

Comment: It's definitely a dupe. But I don't have the target handy right now. Just let it sit and wait for someone to find it and close it for you.

Comment: The appearance of the banner after just one close vote confirms [my suspicion in this comment trail](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/166410/misattributed-posts-and-comments#comment487130_166410). This is vulnerable to abuse.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

as   @Mysticial says this is because those question with one of your favorite tag

[image]