# Two identical usernames?

Tags: support, display-names

[Stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3595405/working-on-arrays-in-php) where the asker and the first answer are the same guy with the same username but different accounts.

How is that possible?

Comment: See [Why does StackOverflow allow duplicate display names?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/25404/why-does-stackoverflow-allow-duplicate-display-names)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Usernames are not required to be unique by the system.

Comment: Would you say its ok for someone to create a account to post a question and then create another one to comment on his question in an answer?

Comment: @izngod, no, it is not ok.  It looks like the user did this on accident.

Answer (score 4):

As @waiwai933 says usernames are not unique on SO, so it's entirely possible for two accounts to have the same name. However, if someone has created two accounts deliberately then that would be sockpuppetry and is not allowed.

However, in this case it looks like either an unregistered user or someone forgot which e-mail address they used to register. Flag one of the posts for moderator attention explaining about the possible duplicate user account.

It's more obvious if the gravatar image is the same.

Comment: My name's Chris Foster, you're in trouble boyo :)