# Help! There are a hundred of me — Puppy Overflow

Tags: support, chat, users, display-names

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Discourage people from using non-unique usernames](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/74704/discourage-people-from-using-non-unique-usernames)
>   [We're all Rebecca Chernoff \o/](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/85591/were-all-rebecca-chernoff-o)

The other Loungers decided to have a bit of fun whilst I was afking, and a truckload of them or so changed their username and Gravatar to match mine. Whilst this was hilarious for a time, now I'm back and some of them can't change back. I've got highlighting for my own messages and even I can hardly tell if I said something or not.

There should be some kind of restriction on this. Also, can you help those other guys go back to their old usernames? Else anyone who comes to visit is gonna be mighty confused... hell, everyone's gonna be mighty confused.

I mean, I might get a bad reputation for some of the things *they* say.

Comment: there's not a hundred, there was like... eight.

Comment: 8? I only counted 5 imposters. Did I miss some?

Comment: They're stuck for 30 days before they can change their name again, the best they can hope for is to change their gravatars.

Comment: That's what happens when you put a cute puppy on your gravatar!

Comment: change _your_ username and gravatar

Comment: @Matt: Are we now?

Comment: @Xeo did you change your name within 30 days? Then I guess not. There is a work around that involves making a new account and updating all your other accounts to be like the new one.

Comment: @Pop: So why didn't you vote to close this as a dupe??

Comment: @sbi because I was joking.

Comment: @Pop: Well, you were right, though.

Comment: @sbi I don't see it... that one is "here's a userscript for impersonating Rebecca," this one is "a bunch of people manually changed their account info to impersonate me; how can they undo it?"

Comment: @Pop: Let's see. Here it's "OMG, a lot of users are impersonating another user for fun!" and there it's... _the same_! (You didn't take this serious, did you?)

Comment: @sbi the important thing is that we've learned that mothers everywhere were right: if you make that face, it _can_ stick that way. (But yes, I did, you got me.)

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd This isn't an Eeeek! question. An Eeeek! question is a "who moved my cheese" question. In this particular case, many things where moved, but no cheese.

Comment: @balpha fair enough - guess I was too eager for more Eeeek! action. :)

Answer (score 10):

I believe they can change their profile name on another SE site if they have linked their account to more than one, then copy that profile to all sites. This is an option when saving your profile, and - at least for now - I'm fairly certain this bypasses any per-site name change restriction.

[image]

Comment: We learned that this will randomly show the 30 day message, or randomly work.  Even retrying the same site would eventually work.

Comment: @MooingDuck interesting, I've only heard of success. <shrug>

Comment: [_copying profile_ workaround](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/45200/add-warning-when-changing-display-name "as described here") helped me change name about three months ago

Comment: Incredibly, [the bug report for this behavior](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/54986/131713) was marked "by design."

Comment: This behaviour changed some time recently. IIRC, you *can* push a name out across the network and it will apply to all sites, including ones that were recently changed, but now it will also reset your name change counter on all sites: you won't be able to pick a new name anywhere for 30 days.

Comment: I'm pretty sure the workaround for *that* is to create an account on a new Stack Exchange site, which won't have the 30-day restriction in effect. But it's been a while since I tested it and I might be mis-remembering.

Comment: @TheElementofMagic: Well, I can confirm that the people in the lounge had to make new accounts on new SE sites to change their names.