# Jon Skeet impersonators running rampant?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, april-fools

At first I thought it was amusing because it is April 1st and thought it was another one of stackoverflow's attempts to troll me. Ha ha. But then I realized that users were changing their profiles to imitate Jon Skeet.

https://stackoverflow.com/users/155407/jon-skeet

https://stackoverflow.com/users/703016/jon-skeet

https://stackoverflow.com/users/298661/jon-skeet

Is this violating a rule, should it be flagged?

https://stackoverflow.com/q/15735552/1026459

Comment: @ElefantPhace it is in UTC.

Comment: It's clearly wrong to me.

Comment: I already flagged them... it's an obvious impersonation and I don't care what date it is.

Comment: Does that count as cosplaying?

Comment: I cite [precedence](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/146974/help-there-are-a-hundred-of-me-puppy-overflow).

Comment: Let's not forget variants like http://stackoverflow.com/users/831108/skeetjon which were active long before April 1st.

Comment: They're not part of the invasion.

Comment: Apparently April 1st is now Stick-in-the-Mud Day.

Comment: @user152637 I wasn't suggesting they were, just that it could be perceived as a different, but somewhat related, problem. While we can't really determine if another user's real name is indeed Jon Skeet (he may be "the chosen one" but he might not be the only one), it seems at least somewhat devious to borrow from his name in any scenario other than coincidence.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

**If** they were just changing their name and Gravatar, then as long Jon Skeet himself doesn't complain about it and they change their names and Gravatars back at the conclusion of the day, I really don't see anything wrong with it. It's the fun of the day.

**However**, copying his age, location, website, *and* complete bio to their own profiles? That's pushing the line. These profile changes should definitely be reversed...

As an aside: if you're going to imitate someone as a prank for April 1, your bio should contain a disclaimer that clearly identifies that you're not the real person.

Comment: i agree, i don't think they should be earning rep on that.

Comment: Unfortunately, names can't be changed for another 30 days.

Comment: @AlEverett: It is technically possible, assuming they didn't apply it globally over all their accounts (which it appears they are doing). I assumed this was a Stack Overflow only thing. I'm sure the moderators will enjoy the after-prank of changing them all back.

Comment: I just flagged posts of all three users mentioned above.

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd To be fair, I don't think it's necessary since the mods are clearly aware of it. You're just giving them more flags to handle...

Comment: Oh, come on; the user ID and the fact that no one has anywhere _near_ as much rep as the real Jon Skeet make this transparent even when just viewing a post by an impersonator.

Comment: @Mysticial more flags means more attention, if there will be only single flag there are less chances the moderator will treat it seriously. For what it's worth, all flags were marked helpful and all three profiles reversed.

Comment: @Josh here on Meta it's totally fine, but not on the main site. New users have good chance to know Jon Skeet but are totally unaware of user ID or how much reputation he got exactly.

Comment: @AlEverett That limitation has a workaround: Sign for a new SE site, then change name in that one (and reflect the change to all others).

Answer (score 17):

The actual Jon Skeet doesn't mind, he said.

https://twitter.com/jonskeet/status/315120626727804928

Comment: Ha, interesting... still, they should have known that it will be more confusing than funny.

Comment: Since I gave my permission, then it's fine

Comment: @JonSkeet: all you deserve now is having all your profiles merged into the original Jon's. (Not really funny, and totally confusing. I really don't like your copying the bio intact, including links.)

Comment: As was commented by myself or one of my clones on the question, there is quite precedence for this kind of prank. As for the bio, then all the stuff Jon Skeet has done and is, is fairly attributed to.. Jon Skeet.

Comment: @JonSkeet: right. And all the stuff _you_ wrote currently appears to be from the real Jon.

Comment: @Mat: Else, it wouldn't be a prank. But secondly, it's pretty flamin' obvious that there are not about 20 Jon Skeets.

Comment: @JonSkeet: it's pretty obvious to you right now. It's totally non-obvious to people coming to SO from search every other second; or people posting questions.

Comment: @Mat: That's what you expect on April 1st.

Comment: @JonSkeet: I expect fun pranks. I don't expect people impersonating others. Especially not high-rep users.

Comment: @Mat: A is B. Also, I am a high-rep user, even if not as high-rep as the real Jon Skeet.

Comment: @JonSkeet: I was saying that I don't appreciate high rep users impersonating others. That makes it even more confusing. People don't necessarily know Jon Skeet is in the half-billion rep-range, 75k is pretty high already, adding to the confusion.

Comment: Seems like I'm a bit late to the party...

Comment: @Mat: All I'm saying is, if you were to take advice offered by this particular "Jon Skeet", you'd hardly be worse off than if you took advice from the actual Jon Skeet. It'll all be back to normal as soon as I stop being sick and decide it's not funny. It's not a big deal and the real Jon Skeet did indeed give his permission for the clone invasion.

Comment: What difference does «It's totally non-obvious to people coming to SO from search» make, @Mat? Is the answer useful or not? Since when are we judging content based on the poster?

Comment: @Josh: Aside from the impersonation, the whole question was a joke: http://stackoverflow.com/q/15735552/1026459. So no, the answer to that was not useful.

Comment: @Felix: That question was closed and deleted inside of 30 minutes. What's the problem?

Comment: @Josh: The question got closed, reopened, deleted, undeleted and deleted again. This whole situation is just inappropriate IMO.