# Why can't I change my name to Jon Skeet?

Tags: discussion, display-names, april-fools, fun

I had the best April Fools' joke idea. I've been brewing it for months. And it flopped.

It involved changing my name and picture to Jon Skeet. (No, that was not the prank itself.) I did that last night, to give it time to propagate over to chat. When I checked this morning, my picture still had Jon's face, but my name had changed back to Kendall Frey.

Why did my name change back to Kendall Frey? Is it some automated system, or did a mod change it?

Comment: Possibly related: http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/174456/148949

Comment: I think we might be preventing name changes on April fools. Not sure though. I think there were so many impersonators that it was blocked. His name gets rep, you know.

Comment: Was my name changed back by a moderator?

Comment: Not a moderator, but a community manager.  A lot of people had the same idea.  I think a bunch of people in chat got together for the same joke.

Comment: Hardly the "best" idea. Not a [patch](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/19479/2509) on [unicorn](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/37328/my-godits-full-of-unicorns) avatars for instance.

Comment: @dmckee I didn't even tell you what the idea was. How can you say it's not good?

Answer (score 39, accepted):

Your name specifically was changed back by Shog9.

Strictly speaking, we have rules against impersonation outlined in the [terms of service](https://stackexchange.com/legal/terms-of-service) (emphasis mine):

> **Under no circumstances will Subscriber use the Network or the Service to** (a) send unsolicited e-mails, bulk mail, spam or other materials to users of the Network or any other individual, (b) harass, threaten, stalk or abuse any person or party, including other users of the Network, (c) **create a false identity or to impersonate another person**, or (d) knowingly post any false, inaccurate or incomplete material.

Now, we aren't *entirely* without a sense of humour (even though [we hate fun](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/01/stack-overflow-where-we-hate-fun/)), so a name change here and there isn't a big deal, especially when it's clear that there is no real intent to impersonate another user. However, once several people start changing their name *and* gravatar *and* copying other profile details without even disclosing that it's a joke, things get weird. We'd rather avoid confusion altogether.

Also, you can only change your name once every 30 days, so this isn't a particularly good choice for a single-day prank.

Comment: I didn't copy any information other than the name and picture. It wasn't intended to be an impersonation, just to fool naive people. I suppose it's for the best if SO doesn't become a zoo on April 1st.

Comment: The irony of *Community* posting this answer is almost overwhelming.

Comment: @Kendall: [a few other people](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/174451/jon-skeet-impersonators-running-rampant) kinda poisoned the well there, IMHO.

Comment: Even though this answer is helpful, it doesn't actually *answer the question*.

Comment: @Kendall Frey: I'm not sure what answer you were expecting. You asked why... and we gave a reason.

Comment: Maybe I should clarify the question.

Answer (score 9):

There's very little chance that anyone would ever want to impersonate me, but if someone did, I would be *furious*. Really, acting in other person's identity is possibly the least amusing idea you could come up with.

Apparently Jon Skeet himself is lenient about it, but I'm glad the moderators take the issue seriously.