# What are all the usernames prohibited to use in stackoverflow?

Tags: support, stack-overflow, profile-page, display-names

I came to know that [it is not allowed](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/174451/jon-skeet-impersonators-running-rampant/174456#174456) to use the name *Jon skeet* as username.

I think that we can't use *community* as a username(not sure).

My question is,

What are all the usernames prohibited to use in Stack Overflow?

Comment: You want a *list*? Hmm... Ok, in alphabetical order: 1) Azik

Comment: Who said they were prohibited in the first place?  Jon Skeet himself said he didn't mind.  Unless they're offensive words/phrases, then I don't know that there are any restrictions on username.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's not that you can't use certain names. It's that you can't intentionally confuse people by making them think you're someone else. From [the Terms of Service](https://stackexchange.com/legal):

> Under no circumstances will Subscriber use the Network or the Service to (a) send unsolicited e-mails, bulk mail, spam or other materials to users of the Network or any other individual, (b) harass, threaten, stalk or abuse any person or party, including other users of the Network, **(c) create a false identity or to impersonate another person,** or (d) knowingly post any false, inaccurate or incomplete material.

So taking the name and picture and bio of one of the top users on the site is likely to get you into hot water. Using the name "Bob" [probably isn't](https://stackoverflow.com/users?search=Bob).

Comment: [Dan](http://stackoverflow.com/users?search=dan) wins big time with 957 exact matches vs. only 432 for Bob, but yeah, the point should be clear enough. ;)

Comment: More accurate link these days is https://stackoverflow.com/legal/terms-of-service/free

Comment: But it applies to Free Teams product, not a public access, what now?