# People creating fake account with name and picture of other StackOverlow users

Tags: discussion, profile-picture, profile-copying

I have this habit of searching Jon Skeet and checking his reputation(inspires me). But when I searched it today, I found **two Jon Skeet**'s as :

[image]

Hoping **Jon Skeet** doesn't have two accounts. :)

[Hoping Not Jon Skeet's profile](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3189338/jon-skeet) *(EDIT: a moderator has reset the offending user's name and image, so they no longer show up as pictured above)*

So this user is using name of famous **Jon Skeet** and using his picture too.

What should be done to these accounts? Can they be reported directly or is this OK to use name and picture of anybody?

Comment: We can only know it's not fake if a mod does an IP xref on them.

Comment: Using **either** the name or the image (assuming public licence etc) would be fine.  Using **both** is impersonating someone and isn't

Comment: And related: [Jon Skeet impersonators running rampant?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/174451)

Comment: @RichardTingle actually if the profile picture is your real life picture, and is being used by someone else it's not legit. So this alone justify flagging, mod should reset it and suspend the offender if he won't stop.

Comment: @ShadowWizard it is highly unlikely that such an image is public domain I agree

Comment: The real Jon Skeet would never ask [such crappy question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/21091160/447356), so this is 100% impersonation. Flagged one the user's posts, hope to see the name and picture being reset soon.

Comment: The fact that you do this regularly is creepy.

Comment: It also seems unlikely the real skeet would steal the answers to that question to [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21090789/2187042) a duplicate of that question

Comment: I do a lot of other creepy stuffs too.

Comment: For the record, I have reset that user's name and image, and am otherwise taking appropriate action.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Looks like a no-no to me.

From the [Terms of Service](https://stackexchange.com/legal)

> Subscriber may not (a) select or use as a profile name a name of another person with the intent to impersonate that person; or (b) use as a profile name a name subject to any rights of a person other than Subscriber without appropriate authorization.

Comment: Claus (b) really needs some clarification

Comment: I may or may not have copied-and-pasted the markdown of your quote above in a message I may or may not have sent to some user who may or may not have violated a certain of the Terms of Service. ;)

Comment: @RichardTingle: It means "don't impersonate anyone else."  Except that it's probably legalese.

Comment: So our old "Bill Gates" and "Steve Jobs" accounts should have been dinged as well?

Comment: @RobertHarvey but thats what claus (a) says as well