# How is it possible that "I" (the user Krumelur) exists twice?

Tags: support, display-names

I was just about to answer a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21537701) about an iOS problem when suddenly a new answer appeared. It was given by me...? At least, that's what the username "Krumelur" indicates.

- [My account with the username Krumelur](https://stackoverflow.com/users/304870)
- [The other Krumelur](https://stackoverflow.com/users/292477)

What really an interesting coincidence:

- Both accounts have been active for almost the same period 3 years and 11 months, respectively 3 years and 10 months.
- Both of us are interested in similar tags
- Both have similar score (+- 2000)

Is this an error or are usernames really not unique? Do I have an evil twin? Or does the other one have an evil twin? :-)

Comment: Usernames are not unique - they never have been.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because [display](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1011939/madara) [names](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1736883/madara) [aren't](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2208051/madara) [exclusive](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1875439/madara).

See [Why does Stack Overflow allow duplicate display names?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/25404/166899) for more details.

Comment: Actually now that I think of it, a duplicate vote would be more appropriate.

Answer (score 0):

Many people can have the same account name. Search for common names on the users list and you''ll get a hundred hits. Email addresses, on the other hand, must be unique. All that would happen is we wouldn't get people using their real names, and adding in special characters